# building text classifier using mahout

Tags: mahout

I want to build text classifier where category will be determined by the text.

Which classifier should I work with?

I have been reading about mahout. Is mahout sufficient. I have about 1Mils documents to train.

I could not find a better example/tutorial of mahout classifier.

Does mahout has http server where I make request and it1 gives me response back?

If not how do I embed mahout in my web app (PHP)

Please suggest some good tutorial on mahout..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your data is not labeled, so I believe you are looking at a clustering problem.

I strongly suggest you start with the [***Mahout in Action***](http://manning.com/owen/) book. The book covers Recommendations, Clustering and Classification. It should have all the information you need to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

NaiveBayesClassifier

Mahout does not have embeded http server, you have to build your own. And the PHP can just request the service as a http client.

There's any demo implementation in Mahout in action, but it is not based on http.

Good luck!